# How to use collection_check_boxes with checked attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

How can i make my collection_check_boxes object to be checked by my model by checked attribute?

I got this as my checkbox form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label><%= car_brand.name %></label>
    <% car_model_each_brand = return_car_model_by_brand(car_brand.id) %>
    <% car_checked_model = return_car_model_by_filter_brand(@selected_model,car_brand.id) %>
    <br>
    <% car_checked_model.each do |car_model_check| %>
        id:<%= car_model_check.id %>  <%= car_model_check.code_name %> ,
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <div class="checkbox">

        <%= collection_check_boxes(:car_insurance_object_model,
                                   :car_model_id,
                                   car_model_each_brand ,
                                   :id,:code_name,
                                   checked: car_checked_model) do |b|
             b.label { b.check_box + b.text }
        end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it is looks like

[image]

[image]

But on Alfa romeo it should be checked on 156 and also
on Audi it should be check on a3.

So how can i fix this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Those look like stylized checkboxes - have you viewed the HTML source and noted the `checked` attribute is indeed missing where you expect it to be present? Also, what is the result without passing in the `checked:` attribute? Rails should automatically assign that unless it requires some specific logic in your back end.

Comment: I already added my HTML source so it still not be checked and without checked: attribute? the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43059625/898716) helped me. Just add a `checked: true` as an argument of check_box. So in your case, it would look like this:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:car_insurance_object_model,
  :car_model_id,
  car_model_each_brand ,
  :id,:code_name,
  checked: car_checked_model) do |b|
    b.label { b.check_box(checked: true) + b.text }
end %>
```

Just remember to change `true` for any other expression that will be evaluated to `true` or `false`.